# How do I add a toolbar to a keyboard extension?

Tags: swift, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard, swift-extensions

I'm building a custom keyboard and I can't find any tutorial or article about that.
What I'm trying to do is adding a toolbar like the one you can see in the screenshot below. As a reference you can even take the suggested words toolbar in the iPhone.
I'm working on a xib file and if I add a toolbar to it, when I run my app it doesn't show.
All of the solutions I found were just for editing the default keyboard when the user uses it in your app. Mine is a custom keyboard.
Sorry if I'm not adding any reference code but since I'm working on a xib file and I don't need anything about functionality but just about appearance I don't it is necessary...

I NEED THE TOOLBAR TO ALWAYS SHOW NOT JUST INSIDE MY APPLICATION.

[image]

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @amone I managed to create it with a collection view. I made the keyboard view bigger and I placed the collection view on top of it. If you still need help lmk and I'll post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for your problem how to create a custom UIToolBar and add to it custom elements like a UIButton etc:

#Swift 5

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


   // will be added later to our custom ToolBar)
   let dragButton = UIButton()

   // the toolbar will appear above a keyboard of the UITextField
   // it can be an outlet from a storyboard also
   let someTextField = UITextField()


  // here is our didLoad method)
  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      someTextField.delegate = self
    
   //For exemple here we call our function what does all the toolbar setups
    setupToolBar()
    
 }

   //setup toolbar
   func setupToolBar(){

    // to add a target for our drag button
    // the target is below the setupToolBar function)
    dragButton.addTarget(self, action:#selector(dragClicked), for: .touchDown)
    dragButton.backgroundColor = .red
    dragButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 4)
    dragButton.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    dragButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "drag"), for: .normal)
    

     // So here we do some stuff with the toolBar
    let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 100))
    toolBar.barTintColor = .clear
    toolBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any, barMetrics: UIBarMetrics.default)
    toolBar.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: UIBarPosition.any)
    toolBar.backgroundColor = .white
    toolBar.isOpaque = false

    //The flexible space helps to arrange things inside the toolBar
    let flexibleSpace = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)

    let ourButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: dragButton)

    // we added 2 flexible spaces to keep are button at the center of the toolBar
      toolBar.setItems([flexibleSpace, hideButton, flexibleSpace], animated: true)
    // and we add our toolBar with our UIButton above our someTextField keyboard)        
    someTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }


   // Ok, here is our selector for dragButton in toolBar 

   @objc private func dragClicked(){
    
      // here we can put some code what our button should perform
        self.someTextField.endEditing(true)

      }

     }
```

Also you can create an extension of UITextField somewhere below a class and there create a custom toolbar